# Show the filtered content on first page instead of show all contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I'm still not familiar with jquery. Based on my code, user can filters the content by clicking "Category 1" or "Category 2" and there are pagination for the content.

Currently, my code shows all the contents on first page and the rest of the pages. What I want is the starting page displays "Category 1" contents only, without clicking any button/link.

The result I want shown below: item 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 13 and 14 are under "Category 1"

[image]

Hoping that some of you could provide me with some advice. Thanks!

```js
var visible = "";
var liToShow = $('li');
$('div.filter').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
  visible = '.' + this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf("#") + 1);
$('ul.items li').hide();
$(visible).show();
liToShow = $(visible);
pagination();
  event.preventDefault();
});

pageSize = 8;
var i = 1;
showPage = function(page) {
$("li").hide();
$("li").each(function(n) {
    if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
        $(this).show();
});        
}

showPage(i);

function pagination(action) {

var pages = Math.ceil(liToShow.length / pageSize);
$('#pager').html("");
for (var i = 0; i<pages; i++) {
   $('#pager').append('<a href="#" class="pageClick">'+(i+1)+'</a> &nbsp;');
}
$('.pageClick').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   showPage($(this).index()+1);
});

}

pagination();
```

```css
ul{list-style: none;}

#item-wrapper {
 width:250px;   
 margin:30px 0 0 30px;
}
.items li {
 font-family:arial;
font-size:13px;
 background-color:#ccc;
margin-bottom:1px; 
padding:5px;    
}
.ctrl-nav {
    background-color:#999;
    padding:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.ctrl-nav a {
    font-family:arial;
font-size:13px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    color:#fff;
}
.ctrl-nav a#prev{
 float:left;   
}
.ctrl-nav a#next{
 float:right;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">
    <a href="#category-1">category 1</a>
    <a href="#category-2">category 2</a>
</div>

<div id="item-wrapper">
<ul class="items">
    <li class="category-1">item 1</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 2</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 3</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 4</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 5</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 6</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 7</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 8</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 9</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 10</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 11</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 12</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 13</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 14</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 15</li>
</ul>

<div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trigger the click of `Category#1` on document ready method like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div.filter a:first-child').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Cool! Works nicely. Thanks for your answer.